# Flutter NFC Write Implementation

Tags: flutter, nfc

I need to write data to a tag via NFC to use in my Flutter application. However, when I run the following code, it gaves me this error flutter: `Instance of 'NfcTag' flutter: error PlatformException(104, Tag is not connected, null, null)`.
I own both NDEF and Type A Tags. Thats why i had to seperate them.
I used https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit package.
And my problem is only for iOS. Android works fine.

```
 Future writeToCard({required BuildContext context}) async {
    var availability = await FlutterNfcKit.nfcAvailability;
    if (availability == NFCAvailability.available) {
      var tag = await FlutterNfcKit.poll(
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 10),
      );

      try {
        if (tag.ndefWritable != null && tag.ndefWritable!) {
          await FlutterNfcKit.writeNDEFRecords([UriRecord.fromString(writeToNfcString)]);
        }
      } catch (ex) {
        print(ex);
      }

      try {
        List<String> data = stringToHexList(writeToNfcString!);
        if (tag.type == NFCTagType.iso15693) {
          await FlutterNfcKit.writeBlock(
            1, // index
            data, // data
           iso15693Flags: Iso15693RequestFlags(),
            iso15693ExtendedMode: false,
          );
        }
      } catch (ex) {
        print(ex);
      }
    }
```

Comment: It also happens to me. If happens, you can just need to read the card again until it works